# trying to use System.getTimeInMillis for user check-in

Tags: android

My question is probably simpler than some... i am developing an app id rather not get to specific about, and due to Non-Disclosure agreements i am not allowed to show my code... however i have come to a stand still. what i need to do, is check if the app has been used in the last 24 hours WITHOUT checking with the server side. so here is the question:

is it possible to use the System clock for this sort of procedure, and establish if the user has checked in? i have had a few attempts, but the timing is always off of the 24 hour mark even if i try to the millisecond.

again i apologize for not being able to share the code, and am hoping there is an easy solution i am missing, even if it is hack-ish! thanks in advance!

edit: to be clear i am using the System.currentTimeMillis() to save it to stored preferences, after checking it against the last value i stored giving me a time difference. i was just wondering if there was some API i missed for this... or maybe an easier method.

Comment: I don't see how we can help to solve a problem on a code we can't see. Are you sure the NDA is about some code to compare two dates in milliseconds ? Chances are big than the core business of the company do has to with something more ambitious ;)

Comment: the server side check in works fine, the client wants to be able to check this without wi-fi so the app is full functionable even when communication is not available... ill edit the question

Comment: Just FYI, I'd suggest not relying on the system millis if this is for some sort of verification or authentication, as a user could easily change their date/time settings to get around it. Pinging an NTP service or setting up a call to your service which can check its own time would be safer.

Comment: thank yo kcoppock i appreciate the advice and will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of your activity's `onResume()` or maybe `onPause()` depending on your definition of last active, add the following:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("some_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putLong("lastActive", System.currentTimeMillis());
editor.commit();
```

Then in the onCreate() or onResume() of your main activity, check this value to see how much time has elapsed.

```
SharedPreferences saved = getSharedPreferences("some_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
long lastActive = saved.getLong("lastActive", 0);

long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActive;
```